# I want to delete elements in object array in when user unselected option in another array using onchangeevent react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to delete selected options in below multiselect  when user de selected in top multiselect. im using onchange for top multiselect  and also for below multiselect.

```
handleChangeMultiBundle(event, data) {
   this.setState(prevState => ({ 
       bundles: event,
       bundle_options_maindoc: event,
       selectedmaindocuments: event,
   }));
}

handlemaindocumentbundle(e, data) {
    this.setState({ selectedmaindocuments: e });
     // want to delete elements in this object when user de select in above multiselect
}
```

when user select above multiselect below multiselect options should get and when user de select in above automatically below multiselect selected value should delete

Comment: Can you post the rest of your component code, particularly the multi-selects. That way we can get a better idea of what you are trying to acheive.